# python object created in C++ going out of scope?

Tags: python, c++, scope, boost-python

I have a project directory that looks like this:

```
|__ __main__.py
|
|__ cppmodules
|        |__ foo.cpp
|        |__ Foo.so
|__ pymodules
         |__ bar.py
```

Inside foo.cpp I have this function:

```
boost::python::object mod;
void set_global(boost::python::object pymod){
    mod = pymod;
}
const boost::python::api::object None = boost::python::api::object();

class MyClass{
public:
    boost::python::object bar;
    MyClass(){}
    void do_stuff(bool param, int param2){
        boost::python::object _bar;
        if (this->bar != None){
            // do something with this->bar
        }
        else{
            _bar = mod.attr("Bar")(param, param2);
            // I overloaded the operator somewhere else
            cout << _bar << endl;
        }
        cout << _bar << endl;
    }
};
```

inside **main**.py

```
from pymodules import bar as bar_module
from cppmodules.Foo import set_global

set_global(bar_module)
```

inside bar.py

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
```

the output was okay for the first cout, but for the second one it returns None:

```
<pymodules.bar.Bar object at 0x7f39f8b94748>
None
```

I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this error and I couldn't manage to replicate it elsewhere (I did manage to get an import error in one case and a core dump in another), but I'm suspecting that it's a problem with reference counting or with anaconda. Is there a way to at least find out what's going on?

Comment: side note: `const boost::python::api::object None = boost::python::api::object();` you can omit the assignment and leave default constructor : `const boost::python::api::object None;`

Comment: Well, it's perfectly fine to overload stream operator like that `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Foo& dt)` (notice no `const` for `dt`). You sure you don't mutate the object there?